# Responsive Menu - Prevent a hover, Use a click instead

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, mobile, responsive-design

I have built a responsive menu for a site I've been working on.

The problem I am having is on an iPhone and all iOS devices, If the ul has a child, It is treating that as an hover and making the menu completley unusable.

I am using [Drop-Down Menu Navigation: Touch Friendly](http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/)

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4u8j/)

My CSS :

```
 #nav
{
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}

#nav li
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 54px;
}

#nav li a
{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #424242;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    display: block;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c55102;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul
{
    position: relative;
}

#nav > ul > li
{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-nav-arrow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

#nav ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

#nav ul li.current_page_item a {
    color: #c55102;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c55102;
}

#nav li.current_page_item ul li a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > a
{
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > a,
#nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* second level */

#nav li ul
{
    background-color: #D1D1D1;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#nav li ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c55102;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#nav li ul li a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #424242 !important;
}

#nav li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

#nav li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul
{
    left: -15px;
}

#nav li ul a:after {
    content: "";
}

#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and ( max-width: 800px )
{
    #nav
    {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav > a
    {
        background: url(../img/icons/icon-nav.png) no-repeat 2% center #D1D1D1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: 55px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: #424242;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 40px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type
    {
        display: block;
    }


    /* first level */

    #nav > ul
    {
        background: #D1D1D1;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

    #nav ul li.current_page_item a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c55102;
    }

    #nav ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #nav li a:after {
        content: "";
    }

    #nav li ul {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav li ul li {
        border-bottom: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #nav:target > ul
    {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    #nav > ul > li
    {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a
    {
        height: auto;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c55102;
        padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
    }

    #nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a
    {
        border-right: none;
    }

    /* second level */

    #nav li ul
    {
        position: static;
        padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Is there any way when the navigation is hovered (On a small screen device) that it takes a click to open its sub menu? I am willing to do this in CSS or jQuery, Whatever is required.

Thanks

Comment: You could use `:active`?

Comment: Hi @BeatAlex I've added :  #nav li:hover ul
 {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

 #nav li:active ul
 {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DO NOT** change `<a>` behavior. `<a>` should be always used to redirect you to a page when clicked, not to expand child `<ul>`. Create a button or anything next to `<a>` which has absolute/relative position against the `<li>` and make sure it has decent padding and higher z (than `<a>`) for easier click. This button will be the trigger for expanding it parent's li child ul.

After that :

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(this).next('ul').css('display','block');
});
```

This will make any click made to the button will expand the `<ul>`

As for "only make it to do so on smaller screen" just **hide those button on larger screen**

I will edit your fiddle later for this solution's implementation

---

**update**

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKze5/3/), sorry, I decided to create it from scratch rather than editing to keep it simple. Resize the result window smaller to make the button appear. otherwise, the button is hidden and default hover action is still being used. hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @AzDesign so are you suggesting an accordion style menu for mobile, Normal sized menu for desktop?

Comment: Yes, but hide the button on larger screen so it won't looks like an accordion

Comment: btw the example is up, check the fiddle above :)

Comment: That seems good to me, Thanks. As its a dynamic menu, I would need the button to load if there are more than 1 item. jQuery?

Comment: You can use a jquery to create the button element for every li that has an ul upon page load. I will update my answer later with the jquery code. I'll comment again when its done

Comment: Brilliant @AzDesign styled it and put it onto my site, Works a treat! Thanks